# How to generate .m/.h files from Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

Is there a convenient way to generate code from any new view controllers I've created on the storyboard? For example when you create a new iOS application, XCode will set up a skeleton class for your view controller.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. You need to create a new ViewController subclass in XCode but uncheck the "Create Xib for this class" box (not sure if that is exactly what it says). Then select your newly made view controller in storyboard and change it to the class you just created.

Answer (score -1):

Ok the skeleton you are talking about is just a template for your application. You are asking for a dynamic template generator from your storyboard and maybe Apple can figure out how to do this in a non distant future but in this moment I think you can't do that. After you created the storyboard file with your complex scheme you need to manually create all your viewController subclass you used in the storyboard. It's not a big deal ... I suppose your application doesn't have thousand ViewController so you can do it manually.

Apple are working hard to simplify developers job but Xcode can't do everything for you.
You can try to post this answer directly to Apple throughout the bugreport Apple website and post it as improvement to implement in future Xcode release.
Lets try it :)